# Running mysql commands with Kubectl

Tags: mysql, kubernetes, ansible

I have **mariadb-gallera** deployed on my Kubernetes cluster and once the pod is deployed and it is up and running I want to get into the pod and login to mysql as root and after that create a database if it is not present over there.

I tried to do so but it fails with errors:

```
 name: "Run command on every Pod labelled app=glaera"
 command: >
   kubectl exec -i "{{ item }}" --namespace backend -- mysql -u'root' -p'YWRtaW4xMjM=' -- 'CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS aves';
 with_items: "{{ pod_names }}"
```

Please help me with a solution.

Error:

```
failed: [localhost] (item=galera-mariadb-galera-0) => {"ansible_loop_var": "item", "changed": true, "cmd": ["kubectl", "exec", "-i", "galera-mariadb-galera-0", "--namespace", "backend", "--", "mysql", "-uroot", "-pYWRtaW4xMjM=", "--", "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS aves;"], "delta": "0:00:00.190892", "end": "2021-02-02 11:57:37.806727", "item": "galera-mariadb-galera-0", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 1, "start": "2021-02-02 11:57:37.615835", "stderr": "ERROR 1049 (42000): Unknown database 'CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS aves;'\ncommand terminated with exit code 1", "stderr_lines": ["ERROR 1049 (42000): Unknown database 'CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS aves;'", "command terminated with exit code 1"], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}
```

Comment: What errors does it fail with. Also galera is replicated. You only need to `create database...` on ONE node.

Comment: I am aware about the fact it is creating replica and i have taken care of it by loping on it, i just need to command to create the aves db once it is deployed.

Adding the error in the original question.

Comment: Look at the first line executed, a) no` '-e "SHOW DATABASES" ` and its not part of  your quoted yaml. Look else in your file and fix the `show database` bit of the code.

Comment: @danblack yes I have fixed the code and updated the error

Comment: Did you try to `kubectl exec` into your `Pod` and run `CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS aves` manually ?

Comment: Did you actually understand that the mysql command is interpreting your full sql query as a database name (which is pretty much what is expected if you review your full command and compare it to instructions in `mysql --help`). Why aren't you passing the query with a `-e` option as described in the documentation ?

Comment: In addition to the other great suggestions, [`connection: kubectl`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.10/collections/community/kubernetes/kubectl_connection.html) for that task (optionally using `raw:` if you don't have python in the container) can make that shell quoting easier to reason about

Comment: @Zeitounator thanks for your suggestion, I used -e and it worked fine.

Comment: @AnujKishor, could you post it as an answer and mark it as accepted it so that it is more clearly visible for others that this issue has already been solved ?

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your command -

```
    - name: "Run command on every Pod labelled app=glaera"
      command: >
        kubectl exec -i "{{ item }}" --namespace backend -- mysql -u'root' -p'YWRtaW4xMjM=' -e 'CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS aves';
      with_items: "{{ pod_names }}"
```

Notice that before `'CREATE` there should be `-e`.

Also, please use `k8s_exec` module instead of the `command` module.

For example,

```
    - community.kubernetes.k8s_exec:
        pod: mysql-deployment-5b68bb45bc-n98lp
        namespace: default
        command: mysql --defaults-file=client.conf -h 127.0.0.1 studentdb -e 'CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS aves'
```